# forward stdin to stdout

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin, stderr

I'm looking for a way to "forward" stdin to stdout in a pipe, while in that step something is written to stderr. The example should clarify this:

```
echo "before.." | >&2 echo "some logging..."; [[forward stdin>stdout]] | cat
```

This should put `"before.."` to stdout, meanwhile `"some logging..."` to stderr.

How to do that? Or is there maybe another quite different approach to this?

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing the question to make some sense?

Comment: Wouldn't `echo "before..." | { >&2 echo "some logging..."; cat; }` do what you want? (This might be too specific to your example, since `echo` doesn't read from standard input.)

Comment: could you maybe provide a refrence to what { } does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution based on your comments:

```
cat ~/.bashrc | tee >( cat -n >&2 ) | sort
```

`cat ~/.bashrc` represents the start of your pipeline, producing some data.

`tee` duplicates its input, writing to both stdout and any files listed as arguments.

`>( ... )` is a bash construct that runs `...` as a pipe subcommand but replaces itself by a filename (something that `tee` can open and write to).

`cat -n` represents modifying the input (adding line numbers).

`>&2` redirects stdout to stderr.

`sort` represents the end of your pipeline (normal processing of the unchanged input).

---

Putting it all together, bash will

- run `cat ~/.bashrc`, putting the contents of `~/.bashrc` on stdout
- ... which is piped to the stdin of `tee`
- run `cat -n` with stdout redirected to stderr and stdin redirected to a new pipe
- run `tee /dev/fd/63` (where `/dev/fd/63` represents the other end of the `cat -n` pipe)
- this is where it all comes together: `tee` reads its input and writes it to both its stdout and to the other pipe that goes to `cat -n` (and from there to stderr)
- finally `tee`'s stdout goes into `sort`

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Redirections follows the simple command they refer to, thus

```
echo "before" >&1
echo "some logging..." >&2
```

should do the trick, if I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: `>&1` is a no-op, though.

Comment: @TheHobbit. Ok, I try to make better example. Say, you want to process some data through several pipe steps. a | b | c | ... at one point you want to log a modified version of the data, e.g. with some line numbers added to them. But at the same time you want to keep processing the unchanged data through further pipe-steps ... d | e | f .

Comment: @AntonHarald Put the details of your question in the question, not a comment on an answer.

Comment: Thus, basically, you need something like tee, able to duplicate its standard input something like echo "foo" | tee /dev/stderr